# Cannot run Mocha.js in synchronous mode

Tags: mysql, node.js, mocha.js

I am testing stored procedures with mocha running in a nodejs instance.  I have this test skeleton:

```
var chai              = require('chai'),
    MyReporter        = require("../MyReporter.js"),
    chokidar          = require('chokidar'),
    expect            = chai.expect,
    should            = chai.should,
    assert            = chai.assert;

var Mocha = require('mocha');
amochai = new Mocha({
   bail: false, 
   debug: true
});

amochai.addFile("mytest_v1.js");

function runMocha(callback) {
    amochai.run(function () {
    callback();
  });
}

watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
      runMocha(function () {});
}
```

**Problem**: My tests are always run in an asynchronous mode, although all my tests are written like this:

```
describe('Mysql stored procedures', function(){ 
   describe('Add this data', function(){
      it('-- Should return this information', function(){ 
         // asserts
      });
   });
});
```

There is no done() callback, I mean nowhere, so, as it is mentioned everywhere that mocha.js is synchronous by default, what could be the reason why my code is running in a asynchronous mode ?

**PATCH**

To patch my problem, I had to use before() and check my tests state, but this becomes a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: What is the symptom that leads you to the conclusion that mocha is running your tests asynchronously?

Comment: I am running those tests in node-inspector, and I can confirm that through breakpoints the tests are run in parallel.  I brought the debugger to the rescue to discover why my tests were incoherent.

Comment: How can you call stored procedures synchronously? you are talking about db storing procedures, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are running operations that are asynchronous in your synchronous mocha tests.

Saying a Mocha test is "synchronous" is ambiguous. It could mean:

- The operation tested by the test happens synchronously.
- Mocha handles the test in a synchronous way.

The two are not equivalent. One does not entail the other. By default Mocha handles all tests synchronously. We can make it handle a test asynchronously but adding a parameter to the callback we pass to `it` (or its equivalent in other test interfaces). (Later versions of Mocha eventually added another way to make Mocha handle a test asynchronously: return a promise. But I'm going to use callbacks for the following examples.) So we can have 4 combinations of synchronicity:

- Operation synchronous, Mocha test synchronous.

  ```
  it("reads foo", function () {
      fs.readFileSync("foo");
      // ssert what we want to assert.
  });
  ```

  No problem.
- Operation synchronous, Mocha test asynchronous.

  ```
  it("reads foo", function (done) {
      fs.readFileSync("foo");
      // Assert what we want to assert.
      done();
  });
  ```

  It is pointless to have the Mocha test be asynchronous, but no problem.
- Operation asynchronous, Mocha test asynchronous.

  ```
  it("reads foo", function (done) {
      fs.readFile("foo", function () {
          // Assert what we want to assert.
          done();
      });
  });
  ```

  No problem.
- Operation asynchronous, Mocha test synchronous.

  ```
  it("reads foo", function () {
      fs.readFile("foo", function () {
          // Assert what we want to assert.
      });
  });
  ```

  This is a problem. Mocha will return right away from the test callback and call it successful (assuming `fs.readFile` does not raise an exeption). The asynchronous operation will still be scheduled and the call back may still be called later. One important point here: Mocha does not have the power to make the operations it tests synchronous. So making the *Mocha test* synchronous has no effect on the *operations* in the test. If they are asynchronous, they will remain asynchronous, no matter what we tell Mocha.

This last case, in your system would cause the execution of the stored procedures to be queued with the DB system. If this queuing happens without error, Mocha finishes right away. Then if there is a file change, your watcher launches another Mocha run and more operations are queued, etc.

Comment: You probably pinpoint my confusion and explained clearly the behavior I am experimenting.  It make sense: I am having asynchronous calls (call to the nodejs mysql module) tested in a synchronous mocha run mode.  I am just surprised that Mocha does not "kind of" wait for a particular callback from the tester to remove this ambiguity from the tester responsability.

Comment: Hi @Louis, 
What would be your suggestion on how to handle the 4th example?

Comment: @Mageshkhanna You have to transform it into the 1st or 3rd cases. In the code I show as example it means use `fs.readFileSync` (1st case) or have the function passed to `it` take a `done` argument, and call it in the callback (3rd) case.