# Gulp Not Working inside Mocha

Tags: stream, gulp, mocha.js

I'm trying to unit test some functionality I've built with Gulp, using Mocha my testing framework. I'm new to unit testing, and have been using the `gulp-concat` [testing](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat/blob/master/test/main.js) as an example.

However, I'm running into an issue where `gulp.src` isn't finding anything when run with `mocha`. I've tried running the exact code from `it` separately, and it worked fine. Run with `mocha`, `gulp.src` isn't entering anything into the stream.

```
var sample = Path.join(__dirname, 'sample.html');
describe('feature', function() {
   it('should do something', function() {
      gulp.src(sample)
         .pipe((function() {
            var stream = through.obj(function(file, enc, callback) {
               console.log(file.path);
               this.push(file);
               callback();
            });
            return stream;
         })());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is asynchronous, so you have to tell Mocha that it is asynchronous and you have to tell Mocha when your test is over.

You tell Mocha it is asynchronous by adding a parameter to the callback to `it`:

```
it('should do something', function(done) {
```

You tell Mocha when the test is done by calling this additional `done()` parameter at the right moment. I went back to the example you used and saw that `assert.end(done)` is used there for this. So your code should be edited to:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var path = require("path");
var through = require("through2");
var assert = require('stream-assert');

var sample = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.html');
describe('feature', function() {
   it('should do something', function(done) {
       gulp.src(sample)
           .pipe((function() {
               var stream = through.obj(function(file, enc, callback) {
                   console.log(file.path);
                   this.push(file);
                   callback();
               });
               return stream;
           })())
           .pipe(assert.end(done));
   });
});
```

Comment: Yup, that worked perfectly! I thought I'd made the test synchronous by not passing in `done`; my bad. Thank you so much; this was driving me crazy!

Comment: Not giving an argument to the callback passed to `it` only tells Mocha "this test is not asynchronous". However, if the code which you have in the test is asynchronous (like the code you are using), then this code does remain asynchronous whether or not you specify the argument. I've gone into such details in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760704/1906307).