# executing event synchronously in mocha

Tags: promise, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise

I'm having trouble running async functions in mocha tests. I'm starting the node server in the beforeEach call and chaining a client socket to connect to it before executing any other it() statements.

the problem is - i'm getting varied outputs with each mocha call

this is my mocha test

//testing events of httpServer

```
import chai,{expect} from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon'
import SocketCluster from 'socketcluster-client';
import testServer from '../../server/server.js';
import net from 'net';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

function startServer(port){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    resolve(testServer(port))
  })
}

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)

describe('httpServer',() => {

  var client;

  var options = {
    port: 4000
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    startServer(4000).then(() => {
      console.log('Server started')
      client = SocketCluster.connect(options)
    })
  })

  it('should return Anonymous user if client doesnt send a valid JWT token on user_connected event',() => {

      return client.emit('user_connected',{id_token:false},(err,data) => {
        expect(data).to.eventually.be.a('string');
      })
  })

})
```

this is the output from the first test call

```
 httpServer
Test server started on 4000
Server started
user connected
    1) "before each" hook for "should return Anonymous user if client doesnt send a valid JWT token on user_connected event"

  Main page
    ✓ should show a sign-in page if isAuthenticated is false (60ms)
    ✓ should show a welcome text if isAuthenticated is true

  SignUp login
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=false on SIGNUP_REQUEST
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=true on SIGNUP_SUCCESS
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=false and errorMessage on SIGNUP_FAILURE


  5 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) httpServer "before each" hook for "should return Anonymous user if client doesnt send a valid JWT token on user_connected event":
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

this is the second call output

```
  httpServer
    1) should return Anonymous user if client doesnt send a valid JWT token on user_connected event
Test server started on 4000
Server started

  Main page
    ✓ should show a sign-in page if isAuthenticated is false (82ms)
    ✓ should show a welcome text if isAuthenticated is true
user connected

  SignUp login
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=false on SIGNUP_REQUEST
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=true on SIGNUP_SUCCESS
    ✓ should return isAuthenticated=false and errorMessage on SIGNUP_FAILURE


  5 passing (347ms)
  1 failing

  1) httpServer should return Anonymous user if client doesnt send a valid JWT token on user_connected event:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (server.test.js:34:14)
```

as you can see , the 'user connected' log happens very randomly. How do i control it to happen synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is that your `beforeEach` hook does not *return* its promise. Removing the curly brackets to make the right side of the arrow an expression should work:

```
beforeEach(() => 
  startServer(4000).then(() => {
    console.log('Server started')
    client = SocketCluster.connect(options)
  })
);
```

Or this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  return startServer(4000).then(() => {
    console.log('Server started')
    client = SocketCluster.connect(options)
  })
});
```

The same rules that apply to asynchronous code in tests applies to asynchronous code in hooks. You have to return a promise or call the `done` callback.

Comment: this works .. but i dont understand why .. is there anything i can read up on to clear my doubts?

Comment: My last paragraph explains the problem: "The same rules that apply to asynchronous code in tests applies to asynchronous code in hooks. You have to return a promise or call the done callback." Now, if you don't know how Mocha deals with asynchronous tests, that's a problem. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760704/1906307) may help.