# Testing style set using Mocha

Tags: javascript, css, mocha.js

I'm trying to test some "style set" functions, and I'm facing issues because I need to wait until the element if fully rendered, then read its property and check if it was sucesfully changed. I know that this is pretty obvious, but I was wondering if there is a way to do the same but without waiting.

For example, I want to test this function:

```
function changeWidth() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.width = '200px';
}
```

And I use this test in Mocha:

```
it('Width should be 200px', () => {
  changeWidth();
  assert.equal(document.getElementById('test').style.width, '200px');
});
```

That assertion will always returns `false`. The following test will work:

```
it('Width should be 200px', () => {
  changeWidth();
  window.setTimeout( () => {
    assert.equal(document.getElementById('test').style.width, '200px');
  }, 1000);
});
```

It has to be a better way to accomplish the same without using timeouts. Can someone guide me? Thanks!

Comment: the test that passes will always pass even if the assertion never passes! you are testing asynchronous logic in a sync test. You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748918/cannot-run-mocha-js-in-synchronous-mode

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I noted:

1. No, you cannot force a render to happen synchronously. The browser decides, so the test will be async and a bit messy. That being said, there are (a bit) more elegant answers than `setTimeout`.
2. Your test is synchronous, while the logic is asynchronous. That means your test will always pass, as the assertion is called after the test has finished (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748918/cannot-run-mocha-js-in-synchronous-mode)). You need to pass a callback to the test that can be called when the test has finished.

You could do the tests somewhat cleaner by using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Just create a helper that will run each function passed to it in a seperate animation frame and you will be guaranteed separate render phases.

```
function runSteps(fns) {
    if(!fns.length) return;

    var current = fns[0];
    var rest = fns.slice(1);

    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        current();
        runSteps(rest);
    })
}

// note the `done` argument - it is what makes Mocha able to know
// when the test is finished. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748918/cannot-run-mocha-js-in-synchronous-mode
it('should run dom render steps chronologically', function(done) {
    function assertWidthChanged(){ 
        assert.equal(
            document.getElementById('test').style.width, 
            '200px'
        );
    }

    runSteps([
        changeWidth,
        assertWidthChanged,
        done
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still a newbie in terms of "testing", so I really appreciate this kind of precision :). Only one question: what do you mean by "testing at the wrong abstraction layer"? In my case I'm developing tests for a jQuery plugin, so I need to be sure that DOM elements have the correct CSS properties.

Comment: Forget it - I am too tired now to understand it myself, and I am not sure I agree with myself anymore. I'll delete that.